# How can I find out how long my slurm job took to execute?

Tags: linux, slurm

One idea I have to find out how long my slurm job *is taking* is to use

```
squeue --job <myid>
```

How do I find out how long my job took to complete though once the job is complete?

Comment: I cannot actually create a slurm tag because my rep is not high enough, but is how I would have tagged it had I the ability to

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `sacct` command:

```
sacct -l -j <myid>
```

and look for the 'elapsed' column

Comment: +1, but more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020420/find-out-the-cpu-time-and-memory-usage-of-a-slurm-job). The output of `-l` didn't fit in my window, so a minimal output is `sacct --format="Elapsed" -j <myid>`.

Comment: This is the best solution yet

Comment: Does this include the Slurm overhead?

Answer (score 9):

```
sacct -j <myid> --format=Elapsed
```

is a very succinct way to show this (Thanks to Sparhawk & damienfrancois for these suggestions, I thought I'd suggest this as a full answer).